# Can we exit from a function (Not from application) or even use a jump to certain line?

Tags: swift, exit

I am looking how to exit in the middle of a function or jump to the end to the function.

I have a function, and inside this function there is couple of verifications to be done. For each verification I am using alertView.

```
        if spacing_CenterToCenter < 2 {

        let alertView = UIAlertController(title: "Stem Rebars Spacing C/C",
            message: "Spacing of Rebars C/C < 2 inches, you must increase the Diameter of Stem Rebars", preferredStyle: .Alert)
        let OKAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Change now", style: .Default, handler: {
            (action: UIAlertAction!) -> Void in
            self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
        })
        alertView.addAction(OKAction)        
        self.presentViewController(alertView, animated: false, completion: nil)
    }
```

Additional codes here

Another verification

```
    if spacing_HorizontalStemRebars < 2 {
        let alertView = UIAlertController(title: "Temp/Shrink Rebars Spacing C/C",
        message: "Spacing of Rebars C/C < 2 inches, you must increase the Diameter of Temperature and Shrinkage Rebars", preferredStyle: .Alert)

        let OKAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Change now", style: .Default, handler: {
            (action: UIAlertAction!) -> Void in
            self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)               
        })
        alertView.addAction(OKAction)
        self.presentViewController(alertView, animated: false, completion: nil)
    }
```

Additional code here

End of function

}

if I run the application and if I have both spacing_CenterToCenter < 2 and spacing_HorizontalStemRebars < 2, I will got the following error:

> 2015-12-15 20:08:02.684 Retaining-Wall[3845:162311] Warning: Attempt to present  on  while a presentation is in progress!

And application will run without error if I have only spacing_CenterToCenter < 2 or only spacing_HorizontalStemRebars < 2.
So, i think to use a command exit or jump to the end of function which will be inside each verification. in this way the function will do only one verification and if fail it will jump till the end of the function.

any advise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could either use `return`, it exits the function if you have no return type.
Or you could use `guard`

```
guard spacing_CenterToCenter < 2 else{
  // Show alert
  return
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well if you are looking for a situation where any "one" condition is enough to display an error simply use else if rather than multiple if's

```
func checking(){
if spacing_CenterToCenter < 2 {

    let alertView = UIAlertController(title: "Stem Rebars Spacing C/C",
        message: "Spacing of Rebars C/C < 2 inches, you must increase the Diameter of Stem Rebars", preferredStyle: .Alert)
    let OKAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Change now", style: .Default, handler: {
        (action: UIAlertAction!) -> Void in
        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    })
    alertView.addAction(OKAction)        
    self.presentViewController(alertView, animated: false, completion: nil)
}
else if spacing_HorizontalStemRebars < 2 {
    let alertView = UIAlertController(title: "Temp/Shrink Rebars Spacing C/C",
    message: "Spacing of Rebars C/C < 2 inches, you must increase the Diameter of Temperature and Shrinkage Rebars", preferredStyle: .Alert)

    let OKAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Change now", style: .Default, handler: {
        (action: UIAlertAction!) -> Void in
        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)               
    })
    alertView.addAction(OKAction)
    self.presentViewController(alertView, animated: false, completion: nil)
}
```

}

In the situation where you ain't looking at something like this, you could make your checking function return a bool and keep track of your bool return in the main function.

In the checking function:

```
func checking() -> Bool {
if spacing_CenterToCenter < 2 {

    let alertView = UIAlertController(title: "Stem Rebars Spacing C/C",
        message: "Spacing of Rebars C/C < 2 inches, you must increase the Diameter of Stem Rebars", preferredStyle: .Alert)
    let OKAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Change now", style: .Default, handler: {
        (action: UIAlertAction!) -> Void in
        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    })
    alertView.addAction(OKAction)        
    self.presentViewController(alertView, animated: false, completion: nil)
//return a false if this get triggered after showing the error
return false;
}

if spacing_HorizontalStemRebars < 2 {
    let alertView = UIAlertController(title: "Temp/Shrink Rebars Spacing C/C",
    message: "Spacing of Rebars C/C < 2 inches, you must increase the Diameter of Temperature and Shrinkage Rebars", preferredStyle: .Alert)

    let OKAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Change now", style: .Default, handler: {
        (action: UIAlertAction!) -> Void in
        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)               
    })
    alertView.addAction(OKAction)
    self.presentViewController(alertView, animated: false, completion: nil)
//return a false if this get triggered after showing the error
return false;
}
//if it has reached this return statement means nothing went wrong and return a true.
return true;
```

}

Now in the main function:

```
var checkReturns = checking();
if (!checkReturns) {
    //your "false" condition processing
}
//your "true" coondition processing
```